# Person - Skills many-to-many and Skill level

Tags: django-models

I'm trying to relate Persons, their Skills and Skill levels. My model looks like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill)
```

and

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

It does work (in admin) and I'm able to create a Person, add several skills etc. However, I also need the skill level information for each Skill related to each Person. Something like this:

```
BASIC = 'BAS'
NOVICE = 'NOV'
INTERMEDIATE = 'INT'
ADVANCED = 'ADV'
EXPERT = 'EXP'

SKILL_LEVEL_CHOICES = (
    (BASIC, 'Basic knowledge'),
    (NOVICE, 'Novice (Limited experience)'),
    (INTERMEDIATE, 'Intermediate (Practical application)'),
    (ADVANCED, 'Advanced knowledge'),
    (EXPERT, 'Expert'),
)
```

I'm not sure what should I add to Person to have information for each skill and its level.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After gathering a little bit more experience on Django, I realized that it offers pretty simple solution to my problem :)

I needed two classes, SkillLevel and SkillWithSkillLevel.

```
class SkillLevel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

class SkillWithSkillLevel(models.Model):
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill)
    level = models.ForeignKey(SkillLevel)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

That's it.

It helps to have a little bit customized admin:

```
class SkillWithSkillLevelInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SkillWithSkillLevel
    extra = 3
```

And then, of course, register SkillWithSkillLevelInline within PersonAdmin, `inlines = [SkillWithSkillLevelInline]`

Person obviously doesn't need `skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill)`.